# Generate random string isn't always returning the correct length

Tags: c++

I am working on a project where I need to generate a random string. It's mostly working, except for some reason, every now and again, the string returned isn't the correct length.

## My Code

```
string HelperMethods::generateRandomString(int length)
{
    static const char alphanum[] =
        "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

    stringstream randomString;

    //Generate a seed for the random number generator
    srand(time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < length; ++i)
    {
        randomString << alphanum[rand() % sizeof(alphanum) - 1];
    }


    return randomString.str();
}
```

I pass in 26 as the length, and I get the following strings returned:

```
s21p7plri418swa279t0nu
u6hf
9for8meeb72hv98n9bc6wqqe3s
qoiovn
```

Why doesn't the returned string always have the correct length?

Comment: Nobody knows because your code has undefined behavior... (small [demo](https://godbolt.org/g/RFUQQb))

Comment: `%` has higher precendence than `-`

Comment: @Rakete1111 That's not helpful at all, why is it undefined

Comment: because your random indices are out of bounds

Comment: I'd recommend always using parentheses `()` to make math expression order of precedence explicit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a NUL character in `alphanum`. After all, it's a C-string. And while you **try** to exclude it, `-` has lower precedence than `%`.

So `rand() % sizeof(alphanum) - 1` is the same as `(rand() % sizeof(alphanum)) - 1`. You are likely accessing before the first element of the array some of the time. That's just plain undefined behavior right there.

Furthermore, you aren't supposed to seed the random number generator more than once. That's likely skewing the results as well. But it isn't as much of an issue as the undefined behavior, of course.

Comment: Ah, yes I fixed it changing it to `randomString << alphanum[rand() % (sizeof(alphanum) - 1)];`. Note adding brackets around the sizeof() - 1 so that's done first

Comment: @Boardy - BTW. You should know that the cstdlib random number facilities are specified in a way that allows for truly bad distribution. There's a slight learning curve involved, but if you want more fine grained control over the distribution, give the modern [`<random>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/random) header a look.

Comment: Thanks for the advice will take a look